# Simple SaveAs Excel Macro query - Need script updating to incl. filename and .xls extension

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel worksheet order form that once completed, I need the end-user to click a button to save the worksheet, before then clicking an email link for sending.

I pulled a simple save script which works fine in bringing up a Save As dialog box, but I now need to add to it:

a) the name of saved file so I can save it as Trans_Order.xls
b) to save it as an .xls so the finished worksheet ideally doesn't contain the macro when sending over email to a 3rd party

Current code is:

```
Sub SaveAs()    
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show   
End Sub
```

Hope you can help - would be grateful for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

The `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` bit saves the file as a macro-free workbook. `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` suppresses an alert that fires saying that the Macro elements won't be saved. It will also suppress alerts about overwriting.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop") _
& "\Trans_Order.xlsx", xlOpenXMLWorkbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

N.B. You may need to include the full path to the workbook in the double-quotes, or it will save back to the folder of your current workbook.

Comment: Hi - this works well, but unfortunately I've lost the save as dialog box to determine the save path - is it possible to get this back, as I need the end user to consciously save it to their desktop so they can then attach to an email? Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Edited answer - the update should automatically save the workbook to the user's desktop. With a little more research, and assuming your end user is using Outlook, you could have VBA automatically attach the file to an email too. Search this site for VBA email examples for more info.